# Renaming C struct properties using SWIG %apply

Tags: swig

I have the below structure in my SWIG interface file and thusly my sample.h header file.  I'm assuming the sockaddr, ios_boolean and unsigned char definitions from this structure are the reason why I get the below generated classes.  If I know the type on that ios_boolean and unsigned char map to on the Java side is there a way to use an %apply to get rid of the generated pointer classes?  I tried %apply int {ios_boolean}; but then I get a SWIGTYPE_p_boolean.java.  Any ideas?

```
%rename (Sample) sample_details_t_;
typedef struct sample_details_t_ {               
    ios_boolean                   is_allowed;           
    unsigned char                 mac[11];        
 } sample_t;


 generates:
 SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char.java
 SWIGTYPE_p_ios_boolean.java
```

Exception:

```
 [exec] ewapi_wrap.c:982: error: `true' undeclared (first use in this function)
 [exec] ewapi_wrap.c:982: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
 [exec] ewapi_wrap.c:982: error: for each function it appears in.)
 [exec] ewapi_wrap.c:982: error: `false' undeclared (first use in this function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do something like:

```
%include <arrays_java.i>
%rename (Sample) sample_details_t_;
%apply bool { ios_boolean };
typedef struct sample_details_t_ {               
    ios_boolean                   is_allowed;           
    unsigned char                 mac[11];        
 } sample_t;
```

This wraps `mac` as `short[]` (with constraints on the array size) and `is_allowed` as `boolean` on the Java side and results in these files:

> Sample.java  test.java  testJNI.java

Make sure you delete any old `SWIGTYPE_*.java` files that are lying around from older versions of your SWIG interface, they won't get deleted automatically and might fail to compile if you do something like `javac *.java`.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion for the ios_boolean and during the SWIG generation I get an error where it seems to not be able to convert from ios_boolean to bool.  I added the exception to the original question as it would be a mess if I added it here.  Any ideas?

Comment: @c12 you want to #include stdbool.h or define true and false constants or include your library's bool header inside the %{ %} at the top of the interface.